# Java Servlets/JSP- How to redirect user to a JSP webpage from a Java page?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I have a register.jsp file, and a Register.java file. The register.jsp collects user input for contact information, then the Register.java file adds that information to my database. However, after that, I need the user to be redirected to my Login.jsp page. Could anyone help me with how can it be done? How do I give the user an option to click a button, or a link, or just redirected him to a JSP page?

Answer (score 1):

after you have saved information in Register.java file try `response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");` in your `public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){}` java function.

Answer (score 0):

write this code for register:

```
@WebServlet("/register")
public class Error extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
        //do operation to adds that information to your database ...
        resp.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
    }
}
```